# How to insert multiselect in a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, multi-select

Pressing the submit button returns the following error:

```
NoMethodError in AuthorsController#create
undefined method `name' for Authorbook:0x007fe6e4284b28
```

and the parameters of the request:

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"/86GsyhAODP55TYKftsW64Lx1Quy5t/hfthlhG9bcto5+B9CwjejJGcMJyr5+IEpA8xi7FehmSv4cMNxvvadUg==",
 "author"=>{"name"=>"hector"},
 "books"=>{"id"=>["",
 "2",
 "3"]},
 "commit"=>"Create Author"}
```

I do not know what happens, apparently the controller receives the name of the author as a parameter and can't handle it.

Models:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true
  has_many :authorbooks
  has_many :books, :through => :authorbooks
end

class Authorbook < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :author
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true
  has_many :authorbooks
  has_many :authors, :through => :authorbooks
end
```

Controller:

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_author, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /authors
  # GET /authors.json
  def index
    @authors = Author.all
  end

  # GET /authors/1
  # GET /authors/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /authors/new
  def new
    @author = Author.new

    @all_books = Book.all

    @author_book = @author.authorbooks.build
  end

  # GET /authors/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /authors
  # POST /authors.json
  def create
    @author = Author.new(author_params)

    params[:books][:id].each do |book|
      if !book.empty?
        @author.authorbooks.build(:book_id => book)
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @author.save
        format.html { redirect_to @author, notice: 'Author was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @author }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @author.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /authors/1
  # PATCH/PUT /authors/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @author.update(author_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @author, notice: 'Author was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @author }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @author.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /authors/1
  # DELETE /authors/1.json
  def destroy
    @author.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to authors_url, notice: 'Author was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_author
      @author = Author.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def author_params
      params.require(:author).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

and the _form:

```
<%= form_for(@author) do |f| %>
  <% if @author.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@author.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this author from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @author.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%= fields_for (@author_book) do |ab| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= ab.label "All Books" %> <br>
      <%= collection_select(:books, :id, @all_books, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true}) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please remove the link to the image showing the error, and copy/paste the error into your question. Images force us to type in the information, which will discourage help for you. Also, the links can rot and break, and when they do your question won't make any sense. See "[mcve]". We don't care about your expertise, we want well researched and asked questions. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages; They'll help you ask better questions.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice.
changes have been already done.

Comment: Does your Authorbook table have a name column? I could be trying to validate the presence of name and this could raise the error

Comment: no, the authorbook table have only 2 columns; author_id and book_id.
the name column exist in the authors table and in the books table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the

```
validates :name, :presence => true #Authorbook
```

in "Authorbooks", because your model doesn't have that field, so basically you are just asking Rails to validate a field that doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks men!. was a very silly mistake.
your reply solves the problem.
see u.